# How to post multiple items to mysql sing < select > option

Tags: php, mysql, smarty

I am working with smarty and would like to know if there is a way to post multiple select items to MySQL. currently on submit of form it stores just one items although the < select > is set to multiple.

here is my code.

```
<select  name="name" class="box-20" multiple="multiple">
<optgroup label="Clients">
{foreach from=$client item=client}
<option value="{$client.FNAME}">{$client.FNAME}&nbsp;{$client.LNAME}</option>
{/foreach}
</optgroup>
<optgroup label="Type">
{foreach from=$type item=type}
<option value="{$type.CTYPE}">{$type.CTYPE}<option>
{/foreach}
</optgroup>
</select>
```

this outputs

Clients

```
<option value="Sam">Sam Adams</option>
<option value="nan">Jan John</option>
<option value="Lincoln">Lincoln Smith</option>
<option value="Julie">Julie Bliss</option>
```

Type

```
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
```

MySQL code

```
if(isset($VAR['submit'])) {
 $sql = "UPDATE CLIENTS  SET 

NAME  =".$db->qstr($VAR["name"])."

WHERE CUST  = ". $db->qstr( $VAR['cust_id']);


    if(!$result = $db->Execute($sql)) {
    force_page('core', 'error&error_msg=MySQL Error: '.$db->ErrorMsg().'&menu=1&type=database');
    exit;
}
}
```

Even if I select them all, it stores just the last option I select in MySQL. 
Thank you all so much!!

Comment: Where is your code that deals with the posted data?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `$_POST['name']` instead `$VAR["name"]`

Comment: **(1)** All of you select options have value of `Sam`, is this an error? Or do you want every value to be `Sam`? **(2)** What is you end goal? `UPDATE CLIENTS SET NAME = Sam Sam Sam` OR `UPDATE CLIENTS SET NAME = Sam, Sam, Sam,` OR `UPDATE CLIENTS SET NAME  = Sam ... , UPDATE CLIENTS SET NAME = Sam`. Don't understand why you want to select multiple names with your query structure.

Comment: sorry about (1) incorrect copy and paste. I've updated the post. my end goal here is for it to save the selected clients name to MySQL. something like Sam Adams, Jan John, Lincoln Smith... etcc

Comment: Then try in you html -> `<select  name="name[]" ...` and in your php implode the names -> `NAME  =".$db->qstr(implode(',',$VAR["name"]), )." `

Comment: had a small error in console with your code above. I've changed it top =".$db->qstr(implode($VAR["name"]) )." and it works perfect. thanks so much

Comment: Updated -> =".$db->qstr(implode(",",$VAR["name"]) )." works perfect.

Answer (score 2):

Change this -

```
<select  name="name[]" class="box-20" multiple="multiple">
```

You can see that I have replaced `name="name"` to `name="name[]"`. What this does is, since you are selecting multiple option, it creates an array of what you've selected.

e.g

```
echo '<pre>'; print_r($_POST['name']);  // will generate following array

Array (
 [0] => client1
 [1] => client2  
 [2] => client3
)
```

Comment: this saves blank to MySQL. any other solutions?

Comment: Can you post your query?

Comment: it does generate the array .. hmm

Answer (score 0):

many thanks to Sean and parag

change php to

```
=".$db->qstr(implode(",",$VAR["name"]) )."
```

works perfect.